# How exactly works this Angular 5 example handling comunication between a parent and child component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-event-emitter

I am starting with Angular and I have some doubts about how exactly works this example related to comunication between a parent and a child component.

So I have this PARENT COMPONENT. This component is used to show a list of items (each item is represend by the child component). Interacting with this component I can add and remove items from this list of items.

This is the parent Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html'
})
export class ProductsComponent {

  productName = 'A Book';
  isDisabled = true;

  products = ['A Book', 'A Tree'];

  constructor() {

    setTimeout(
      () => {
        this.isDisabled = false;
      }, 3000)
  }


  onAddProduct() {
    this.products.push(this.productName);

  }

  onRemoveProduct(productName: string) {
    this.products = this.products.filter(p => p !== productName);
  }

}
```

And this is its template :

```
<h1>My Products</h1>

<input *ngIf="!isDisabled" type="text" [(ngModel)]="productName">

<button *ngIf="!isDisabled" (click)="onAddProduct()">Add Product</button>

<app-product
    (productClicked)="onRemoveProduct(product)"
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    [productName]="product">
</app-product>
```

Then I have the child component representing a single item of the list handled by the parent component. This is the child Component :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent {

  @Input() productName: string;

  @Output() productClicked = new EventEmitter();

  onClicked() {
    this.productClicked.emit();
  }

}
```

And this is te children template :

```
<article class="product" (click)="onClicked()">
  <div>{{ productName }}</div>
  <p>An awesome product!</p>
</article>
```

Ok, now I have some doubts about how these 2 components interact together:

In the parent component template :

```
<app-product
    (productClicked)="onRemoveProduct(product)"
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    [productName]="product">
</app-product>
```

that is referring to the child component (labeled by **app-product**).

It seems to me that basically I am iterating on the **products** list defined into the parent component class (an array of strings) and that each of these string is passed to the `productName` variable defined into the child component class, to do it I am using the `@Input()` decorator on this property in the child component class:

```
@Input() productName: string;
```

Basically this **@Input()** decorator hallow the parent component to "inject" the value into the child component property at each iteration.

Is it? or am I missing something?

Then I have the behavior that handle the item removal from the items list: when an element of the list is clicked (implemented by the child component). This element is removed from the list (and so from the page).

How it works (my idea):

Each element is represented by this code in the child component view:

```
<article class="product" (click)="onClicked()">
  <div>{{ productName }}</div>
  <p>An awesome product!</p>
</article>
```

When an object is clicked it is performed the `onClicked()` event into the child component class. I can't remove the selected object directly from the child component class because the array of items is defined into the parent component class. So this method emit an event:

```
  onClicked() {
    this.productClicked.emit();
  }
```

having "type" productClicked (is it an event type or what?). This event is received in the parent component view:

```
(productClicked)="onRemoveProduct(product)"
```

that call the `onRemoveProduct(product)` method that remove the object having this name from the array.

Is it correct or in my reasoning am I missing something?

Another doubt is: is it a neat and correct way to handle events and this kind of situation?

Comment: Everything you have explained is correct and that's exactly how you should handle that kind of communication. Kudos!

Comment: It looks correct. I see nothing that I wouldn't do in a different way, after working with Angular for 1.5 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in both cases !

And according to the [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), this is a correct way to handle communication between parent/child components.